# FB graph api for test users: how to set the test user's “gender”

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I create test users for testing my application, I was able to change the locale, but i can not understand how to have a test user to change gender? from Graph API
Is it possible at all to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/app/accounts/test-users
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/test-user/#publishing

You can only set some fields' contents with the Graph API. `gender` is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response